# React -- Modal opens for every element in a mapped array, regardless of which one is clicked

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-functional-component

So I am mapping over an array of items, and am wanting to open up a unique Modal for whichever one is clicked. For some reason, if I click any of the items, a Modal pops up for each of the items. Here is my code

```js
const PrivateProjects = props => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const openModal = () => {
        setShow(true)
    }

    return (
        <div className='projectContainer'>
            {privateProjects.map((project, index) => (
                <div className='lightbox' onClick={() => {openModal()}}>
                    <div className='project'>
                        <h5>{project.name}</h5>
                        <img src={project.image} alt='hibiscus project' />
                    </div>
                    <MyModal title={project.name} img={project.image} show={show} onHide={()=> {setShow(null)}}/>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default PrivateProjects;
```

Here is MyModal

```js
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

const MyModal = (props) => {
    console.log(props);

    return (
      <Modal
        {...props}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            {props.title}
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <img src={props.img} />
          <p>
            Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
            dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac
            consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
          </p>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }

export default MyModal;
```

Also, the buttons to close the modal aren't working either, only the escape key works. Not sure where I am messing up with that.

P.S. I took out the imports and array of objects for the sake of visibility, because it's a lot of data and works fine.

[image: here is a pic of what happens with the modals]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because they are all using the same `show` state.

The code below is similar to the structure you have after `map` is executed:

```
<MyModal title={project.name} img={...} show={show} />
<MyModal title={project.name} img={...} show={show} />
<MyModal title={project.name} img={...} show={show} />
```

So, when `show` gets true, they all open.

You could solve this by using different states for each of the Modals.

Example:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState([false,false,false])

<MyModal title={project.name} img={...} show={show[0]} />
<MyModal title={project.name} img={...} show={show[1]} />
<MyModal title={project.name} img={...} show={show[2]} />

<button onClick={()=>setShow([false, false, true])}>Open Modal 3</button>
```

Comment: Great. I found a solution that accompanied your answer, so this was very helpful. Thank you very much! Will post the answer now

Answer (score 1):

```js
const PrivateProjects = props => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState([false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]);

    const openModal = (index) => {
        handleChanges(index);
    }

    const handleChanges = (index) => {
            // 1. Make a shallow copy of the items
            let items = [show];
            // 2. Make a shallow copy of the item you want to mutate
            let item = items[index];
            // 3. Replace the property you're intested in
            item = true;
            // 4. Put it back into our array. N.B. we *are* mutating the array here, but that's why we made a copy first
            items[index] = item;
            // 5. Set the state to our new copy
            setShow(items);
    }

    return (
        <div className='projectContainer'>
            {privateProjects.map((project, index) => (
                <div className='lightbox' onClick={() => {openModal(index)}}>
                    <div className='project'>
                        <h5>{project.name}</h5>
                        <img src={project.image} alt='hibiscus project' />
                    </div>
                    <MyModal title={project.name} img={project.image} show={show[index]} onHide={()=> {setShow(false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false)}}/>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default PrivateProjects;
```

I feel like there may be a simpler solution, but this is what got it to work for me!